# How to set annotation of hrect referenced to a secondary y axis

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using plotly to create some charts. I have 2 y axis available and I'm creating some horizontal rectangle referenced to a secondary y axis. Which is working fine, hrect is displayed where it has to be. But problem is that annotation linked to that hrect is not being referenced to that secondary axis. So I get a mess in representation.
This is how I define hrect

```py
     fig.add_hrect(y0=current_quantile, y1=current_quantile, fillcolor="black",
                   annotation_position="bottom right", annotation_text="Current performance",
                   line_width=1, secondary_y=True)
```

And this is what I get

[image: Annotation wrong location]

If I modify html code and change annotation `yref` to `y2` then it works as expected.

[image: Annotation properly located]

In my point of view this looks like a bug from plotly, if you are referring hrect to secondary axis, it has no sense that its annotation references to another axis. But I was wondering if there is some workaround which could allow me to fix this. I've tried to define `annotate=dict(yref="y2")` but no luck, the same with `annotation_yref="y2"`
According to official documentation, not sure if yref can be changed in hrect call
[image: Annotation reference]

Thanks a lot for your help

Edit for adding a while chart representation to focus over 2 y-axis information being displayed.

[image: Left refers to number of items and second refers to timestamp]

Comment: What is the data type of the x-axis? Why do you need to use a second axis? I think there is not enough information for anyone to answer such questions as Can you provide the minimum data and all codes that can confirm the event?

Comment: I'm using 2 y-axis, not 2 x-axis. In left I'm using ```int``` representation and in right using ```timestamp```. Main one is ```int``` type, so when you create a new ```hrect``` if you don't specify you are referring to other axis (```seconday_y=True```), by default it would be treated as primary y-axis. Editing main in order to include a complete chart image.

Comment: Does it fit how to add annotations separately from the rectangle instead of annotating with a rectangle?`fig.add_annotation()`

Comment: `current_quantile` What are the actual data for this variable?

Comment: A timestamp which has sense to secondary y-axis. That is being properly considered. You can see black line (I've cheated ```hreact``` instead of using ```hline``` due to this second one does not allow timestamps). In my updated chart, green square and black are hrect, which is fine. Problem is labeling these hrects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- started by creating a figure with two yaxes
- I did find that `yref="y2"` is being ignored by `add_hrect()`
- hence resolved by moving to `add_shape()` and `add_annotation()`

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

r = np.random.RandomState(22)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.linspace(0, 100, 50),
        "y1": r.uniform(1, 10, 50),
        "y2": r.uniform(30, 50, 50),
    }
)

# create a figure with two yaxes
fig = (
    px.line(df, x="x", y=["y1", "y2"])
    .update_traces(yaxis="y2", selector={"name": "y2"})
    .update_layout(yaxis2={"side": "right", "range": [0, 50], "overlaying":"y"})
)

current_quantile = 25
# wrong place for text
# fig.add_hrect(
#     y0=current_quantile,
#     y1=current_quantile,
#     annotation_position="bottom right",
#     annotation_text="Current performance",
#     yref="y2",
#     xref="paper"
# )

# correct position for text
fig.add_shape(
    type="rect",
    yref="y2",
    xref="paper",
    y0=current_quantile,
    y1=current_quantile,
    x0=0,
    x1=1,
)
fig.add_annotation(
    yref="y2",
    xref="paper",
    y=current_quantile,
    yshift=10,
    x=1,
    text="Current performance",
    showarrow=False
)


fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I assume that at the end it's what hrect is doing, creating a shape and an annotation. I continue thinking this is a plotly hrect bug.  I has no sense hrect creates 2 figures, annotate and shape  , and just one is considering secondary_y variable. I cannot imagine any situation where you want to draw a line in one axis but label info referring to another axis.

Comment: I did run it through a debugger,  couldn't see where it was going wrong...